# How to make my application compatible with Smart TVs?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hello there I have an app which is compatible with Phone/Tablet and my TV Android Box . 
However this app is not compatible with my Android Smart TV itself , like when i go to google play (which is Alpha) i get the text saying that the app is not compatible with the device.

I did some checks and I found that the app's menifest should mention that this is a LEANBACK_LAUNCHER, which I did like the following code:

```
[Activity(Label = "Afaq.IPTV", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] {"android.intent.action.MAIN"}, AutoVerify = true,
        Categories = new[] {"android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"})]
    public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
    {...
```

So am I missing something ? has anyone succeeded with this before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

In the mainActivity you start the class the way I did in the Quesiton

```
[Activity(Label = "Afaq.IPTV", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new[] {Intent.CategoryLauncher,Intent.CategoryLeanbackLauncher})]


public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
{...
```

In the manifest you have to add the following

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
```

After adding this line you will have an app that is available on Google Play store from your TV. However, if you have only this in the manifest then your app is not compatible with your touch screen devices (e.g. phones and tablets). Google this problem and you might find something useful which would solve this problem. My guess is by having another Activity that is for phones .

Comment: You mean that we should create better a separate project for TV

Comment: No you can have it on the same project so you can get one APK for both . but of course you need to separate between views that are targetting TV or Phone ,

Comment: I think that it makes more sense to create another project and separate views and use shared viewmodal code in order to keep app size smaller.

Comment: By another project you mean Android project or  PCL project ?

Comment: I mean adding another Android project in same solution and Reference shared Code pcl or Net Standard

Comment: No because with that you will have two APKs one for TV and one for the phone , what you need is one Android project that has two PCL projects one for TV and one for Phone and when you detect the device in the android project if it is a phone then load the phone project if it was a tablet or tv then you can you load the TV PCL project. 
Another way is to have one droid project and one pcl project and different pages for TV and Phone which you navigate between them based on the device type .

Comment: I said 2 android projects because if you go through google documentation, there are several settings needs to be enabled and even manifest should have touch disabled for tv app. i am not sure if you can have 2 manifest for 1 project. even if you can, i wouldnt like to mix settings together. Regarding what you say, if you have 2 pcl, you need to reference on single android project, both will be archived into apk and this will bloat apk size unnecessarily. It is really difficult architecture.

Comment: No not really , if you follow the steps I have in my post here , you will have it for both TV and Phone and this is by google themselves . You do not remove the touch , but you remove the requirement part of that .  
and regarding the size , few extra megas will not make a big difference . Facebook , YouTube and many other famous projects are over 600 MBs

Comment: i have a problem google dev console saying "No full-size app banner" even i added the banner in the manifest ...

Comment: I think that means you need to add an image in the play store for TV